# Set specific digit range jquery.mask

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mask

I need the first digit to be from [1-9], which would omit the 0.
So i tried something like

```
$("#myid").mask("[1-9]999999999");
```

Is there a specific work out for mask library?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the [source code](https://github.com/digitalBush/jquery.maskedinput/blob/master/src/jquery.maskedinput.js) we have:

```
$.mask = {
    //Predefined character definitions
    definitions: {
        '9': "[0-9]",
        'a': "[A-Za-z]",
        '*': "[A-Za-z0-9]"
    },
    autoclear: true,
    dataName: "rawMaskFn",
    placeholder: '_'
};
```

So, stick this line somewhere after you've loaded the library:

```
$.mask.definitions['1'] = "[1-9]";
```

Then this should work ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3Udgs/)):

```
$("#myid").mask("1999999999");
```

Comment: that was so simple, thank you for saving my time. it's really apreciated.